# Powershell equivalent to curl --resolve

Tags: powershell, curl, spoofing

I need to use powershell to check the https response code of a call where the DNS entry isn't setup or points at an IP that cannot be reached. The command is run on the same server as the IIS hosting the application. IIS site is setup with https only, the below shown port, and with a DNS name of "dns-name.com" and a valid certificate. I have tried this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$url" -Headers @{ Host="$httpHost" }
```

, where $url is something like this: "https://127.0.0.1:1234/some.endpoint.svc", and $httpHost is something like "dns-name.com"

This fails:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

However, downloading curl (to see if this is an IIS or Powershell issue) and using this works:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" https://dns-name.com:1234/some.endpoint.svc --resolve "dns-name.com:1234:127.0.0.1"
```

My powershell attempt works just fine with http, just not with https.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here and guess that it has something to do with [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). This cannot be faked by sending a header, since the SNI host has to be sent before the TLS connection is established. No idea how to fix this in PowerShell though, but changing your hosts file should allow you to work around it.

Comment: It turned out to be that the endpoint wanted TLS1.2 which the client didn't send. I forced the use of TLS1.2 in powershell and then Invoke-WebRequest worked just fine.